# Overloading +=, +, ==, and != operators

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why must we define both == and != in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916884/why-must-we-define-both-and-in-c)

Why is overloading of += possible only by overloading of +, but == and != are separately overloaded?
It seems it should be inverted.
+= overloading is nearly always possible to write more effective because it's unnecessary to allocate memory for new object. But I can't invent an example in which operators == and != should be different in something except inverting the result Equals().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A similar question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916884/why-must-we-define-both-and-in-c/6919149).

The biggest reason is that when you overload the `==` and `!=` operators, you don't have to return a boolean.  If you're not returning a boolean, you can't just invert the complimentary operator.  There are other possible reasons they are separately overloaded, you can view the answers to that question for those other reasons.

There is a valid reason you can't overload `+=` and therefore it is done implicitly via the `+` operator.  I has to do with the fact that you can't override the assignment operator in C#, it's part of the language standard.  The `+=` is increment and assign, the latter of which you can't overload in C#.

Comment: +1 Just imagine the craziness if you could overload `+` and `+=` separately...

Comment: If C# and .net didn't do evil things with mutable structures (mutable structs aren't evil--some things .net does with them are), or if they allowed classes to restrict the evil promiscuous sharing of references to their objects, it would be useful to have separate += and + operators, since using the "+" operator would imply making a copy and leaving the original untouched, whereas "+=" implies the original can be modified.  Note, btw, that events support "+=" and "-=", but do not support "+" and "-".